# Parse json string into knockout observables

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am getting the following response from a REST endpoint and I need to populate a dictionary with the values. The json looks like this: {"name":"A", "id:"A", "properties":{"description":"A", "text":"A", "number":"one"}} Eventually, I'll be getting an array of this json objects.

I tried the following in my ajax success callback:

```
    console.log(result)
        for (x in result){
            console.log(result[x])
            if (x  === 'object'){
                for (y in x){
                    console.log(x[y]);
                }
            }
        }
```

This really isn't what I want. I need to be able to load the property values into knockout variables if a user selects the name.

Comment: When you use ko.mapping.fromJS each property is converted to an observable and each array is converted to an observableArray -- see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two sides to your problem:

- Converting your data from a json string to a *view model*
- Managing the UI and make sure it can handle (external) data changes without loosing state

### Converting json to a viewmodel

This can be done automatically (for example, via the ko-mapping plugin linked in a comment), or manually. I'm in favour of manual mapping. The basics:

1. Parse JSON.

   E.g.: from `'{ "name": "A" }'` to `{ name: "A" }`
2. Add functionality via `prototype`, `observable` or `computed` properties.

   E.g.: from `{ name: "A" }` to `{ name: ko.observable("A"), index: 0,
   /* ... */ }`

### Managing state & external data changes

Once you've created an array of viewmodels, you'll need a place to manage the selection. The basics:

```
this.items = ko.observableArray([ { name: "A" }, { name: "B" } ]);
this.selection = ko.observable(items[0]);
```

You can data-bind the items and selection to your UI. For example, using a `<select>` element:

```
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'name', value: selection></select>
```

This completes the chain: `json` > `array of objects` > `array of viewmodels` + `selected viewmodel reference`.

Now, the only challenge is to make sure you can reload data from the server without loosing the selection. To do so, you can either add an `update` method to your viewmodel that sets observable properties, or replace all viewmodels and store a selected `id` rather than a reference to an object.

All together in an example:

```js
var createItem = function (obj) {
  // Up to you how you map to "viewmodels", 
  // If you want two-way binding (for editing),
  // wrap in an observable.
  // Example for 1-way binding
  return Object.assign({
    name: obj.name,
    id: obj.id,
    randomNr: Math.random()
  }, Object.keys(obj.properties).reduce(function(res, key) {
    res[key] = obj.properties[key];
    return res;
  }, {}));
};

var VM = function() {
  this.rawData = ko.observableArray([]);

  // Create "item" view models from the array of objects
  this.items = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.rawData().map(createItem);
  }, this);
  
  // Store items by `id` prop. (Could also be a plain object)
  var itemMap = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return new Map(
      this.items().map(function(item) {
        return [item.id, item];
      })
    );
  }, this);
  
  // Store the id of the selected item
  this.selectedId = ko.observable(null);
  
  // Whenever either the selected id, _or_ the  array of items changes,
  // update the selected item
  this.selectedItem = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return itemMap().get(this.selectedId());
  }, this);
  
};

VM.prototype.loadData = function(json) {
  // Hardcoded
  json = '[{"name":"A", "id":"A", "properties":{"description":"A", "text":"A", "number":"one"}}, {"name":"B", "id":"B", "properties":{"description":"B", "text":"B", "number":"two"}},{"name":"C", "id":"C", "properties":{"description":"C", "text":"C", "number":"three"}}]';
  
  // Might want to wrap in a try catch
  this.rawData(JSON.parse(json));
}

var vm = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<select data-bind="options: items, 
                   optionsText: 'name', 
                   optionsValue: 'id',
                   value: selectedId"></select>

<p>Your selection:<p>
<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
  <h3>Name: <span data-bind="text: name"></span></h3>
  <h4>Description:<span data-bind="text: description + randomNr"></span></h4>
  <p>Nr:<span data-bind="text: number"></span></p>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: loadData">load data</button>
```